# layout_weight not working with LinearLayout inside Drawerlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, drawerlayout

I'm struggling with LinearLayout when using DrawerLayout.  This is using the Android Studio template for DrawerLayout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#00f"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#f00"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
     android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
<!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container. -->
<fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:name="com.test.testdrawerlayout.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The preview in Android Studio shows this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmbxX.jpg

However, when running on my Nexus 5, the following shows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIzwk.jpg

As you can see, the layout_weight="1" part is not showing at all.  When I create a blank project with the inner LinearLayout however, the layout works (with the blue layout taking most of the screen with the red layout at the bottom, just like the preview).

Any ideas would be really appreciated, as I'm completely stumped right now.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: For DrawerLayout, I think you'd better use a frameLayout as your content container, and put the linearLayout in the frameLayout. Then it should work.

Comment: I tried adding frameLayout to wrap around the LinearLayout.  The same thing happened.

Comment: OMG, Exactly what I wanted to ask!

Comment: For me, a simple layout with weights was working, but a more complex one was not. I have not isolated the broken piece of the puzzle yet, but none of the below solutions worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears I was using an older Android SDK platform.  Once I went into SDK manager and installed API 19, it worked (with a new project).

Maybe it was a bug in an older implementation?

Comment: Make sure to test if it runs on earlier API. I would still recommend you see what I told you about using the android:weightSum because your linearlayouts can prove to be problematic in the future if not properly designed.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely an Android issue (or at least `appcompat/design` library issue). I've tested with different layouts inside the DrawerLayout, and concluded that the problem was "`content_layout`" file - the one that is displayed below the drawer.

Only using a clean, plain FrameLayout worked. No CoordinatorLayout, no fragments, no custom layouts nor 3rd-party layouts, just a good old FrameLayout with "`match_parent`" as width and height.

Answer (score 0):

1. Inside the drawerlayout you should have a FrameLayout which contains the main content for your screen and you should also have a ListView in most cases to hold the contents of the navigation drawer.

It should be as such:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

1. Now place your LinearLayout within the FrameLayout. Think of the FrameLayout as the "container" that holds your main screen.

Note that the official Android documentations state that

> The    main content view (the FrameLayout above) **must be the first
>   child**    in the DrawerLayout because the XML order implies
>   z-ordering and the    drawer must be on top of the content.

For more reference and information, I would advise you check this link by clicking [here](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#DrawerLayout).

Please mark this as the answer if it solved your problem. Thank you.

**UPDATE**:

Okay first, remove "xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"" from your linearlayout. That should only appear once and in the main root xml, in this cause the DrawerLayout.

Next, fix how you are using your weights. Declare a android:weightSum attribute. Think of weightSum as a pie. In this case we set it too 5, so we have 5 pieces of the pie. Anything inside this layout using the android:layout_weight attribute. This first one is set to 4, which will take 4/5ths of the screen. The last one is 1/5th of the screen at the bottom.

Make sure this LinearLayout is still wrapped within the FrameLayout. Your LinearLayout should appear as such:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="5">
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#00f"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#f00"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, using FrameLayout with my LinearLayout inside did not work.  The same behavior occurred on my Nexus 5.

Comment: @Farplaner See my updated answer, I believe I solved your problem. You were using the weight attributes wrong. You should have been using android:weightSum in the parent and android:layout_weight for the nested child layouts. Please mark this as this answer if it worked out :)

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer.  However, it still didn't work for me.  Something else must be causing my problem though.  It only works for me now with a new project, with the new API.  I can't go to an existing project and change API/sync gradle.

Comment: Wrapping everything in a `FrameLayout` doesn't fix this issue for me. Using `weightSum` does not fix it either.